# How to use stable lookup in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel formula that works on only two lines. When I add another line to the sheet, it no longer looks up correctly.

My current formula is:

```
=LOOKUP('Data Entry'!F6,Invoice_Data!A2:B999,Invoice_Data!B2:B999)
```

I feel I need to use index or match or both but i can not get it work across multiple sheets, and columns.

I am trying to match "Sheet1 F6" and "Sheet1 F7" with "Sheet2 A:B999" and "Sheet2 E2:E999", and return the value in "Sheet2 B2:B999" in Sheet3 any location.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: `Sheet2 A:B999` this looks wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested):

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B999, 
       MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A2:A999=Sheet1!F6)*
               (Sheet2!E2:E999=Sheet1!F7),0))
```

Enter as an array function using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.